# How to categorize a continuous variable

Tags: sas, percentile, categorization

In `SAS` I have a continuous variable that go from `0` to `1`. I want to categorize it in `10` classes in base to `10 percentiles` that I have. There is a `PROC` or a function that take as input my continuous dustribution and the percentiles and compute the categorization?

How can I fix?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proc rank or proc univariate to do this. Have a look at the docs and ask a more specific question if you run into problems once you've actually written some code.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the round function `ROUND(argument, rounding-unit);`. For example:

```
data table;
set table;
roundedVar = ROUND(continuousVar, 0.1);
run;
```

That will give you 11 unique classes (0 , 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1). Look into the FLOOR() and CEIL() functions if you want 10 classes.

Comment: This doesn't percentile anything though, and that's the real question here. Round/floor/ceil would produce buckets of unequal size

Comment: @superfluous correct, this approach would only bucket the observations based on the range they fall in.